# Spark kafka connector throwing nullpointerexception after writing the messages into the broker

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark kafka driver to write a dataset into a kafka broker.
Below is the sample code:

```
dataset
   .write()
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaProducer.getKafkaBrokerUrl())
   .option("topic", kafkaProducer.getTopic())
   .option(KEY_SERIALIZER, kafkaProducer.getKafkaConfig().getKeySerializer())
   .option(VALUE_SERIALIZER, kafkaProducer.getKafkaConfig().getValueSerializer())
   .save();
```

Although this is writing the contents of dataset into the broker, I'm getting the below error for every record in the dataset.

```
ERROR ProducerBatch:207: Error executing user-provided callback on message for topic-partition 'Kafka-topic-0'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1422)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:591)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:567)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:692)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I went through the [spark structured streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka) and there is nothing mentioned about the callbacks. I'm using the below library dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.kafka.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: is the kafka/spark cluster on same host ?

Comment: @Chandan: its in a different cluster. I'm able to write data into this host. But after writing the data, I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. The only suspicion I have is on the dependencies used (not sure if there is a bug in that particular version). Here are the exact versions using which I did not run into any issues. Please test the same thing with these versions and lets see if this helps.

If this did'nt help may be you can update the question with your complete pom.xml so that we can look into this further

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Let me try this out.